# Hidden input does not pass the value to the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

I have couple of input fields in my form, which are getting passed to the server, but one of the inputs is hidden and has value set, unfortunately I am not getting the data from that input.

Example of HTML FORM and input, that does pass the values:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} data-netlify="true" method="post">                                
       <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Example of hidden input, that does not pass the value

```
<input type="hidden" name="cart" value={myJSON}></input>
```

Each value is stored as a state

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
const [company, setCompany] = useState('');
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
const [cart, setCart] = useState('');
```

And my handle submit:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (name && emailIsValid(email) && phone && company && message && cart) {
            fetch('/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body: encode({
                    'form-name': 'landing-form',
                    name: name.trim(),
                    email: email,
                    phone: phone,
                    company: company,
                    message: message,
                    cart: cart,
                }),
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    redirectAfterSubmission();
                })
                .catch((error) => alert(error));
        }
    };
```

The value of hidden input - `{myJSON}` is a pretty array of objects that has been picked to the "shopping cart" and `console.log(myJSON)` shows the correct values, so I don't know why it won't pass to my server.

Comment: Why do you need that hidden input? You can send that cart value directly in your fetch's body. Or you can initialize your state like const [cart, setCart] = useState(myJSON); If you really need it and send that value and read it in some API, i would use JSON.stringify in that input value anyway.

Comment: myJSON is already version of JSON.stringify `const myJSON = JSON.stringify(updatedCart, null, 4)`, how would I pass the `cart` directly in body? I wanted to do hidden input that will contain my cart, so it can be send together with my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out - I was passing wrong value in `handleSubmit`:

```
body: encode({
                'form-name': 'landing-form',
                name: name.trim(),
                email: email,
                phone: phone,
                company: company,
                message: message,
                cart: myJSON,    // cart value is replaced by myJSON
            }),
```

And I deleted `const [cart, setCart] = useState('');`, since I was not using it to anything.

I also changed input to text area, but I think either of it should work:

```
<textarea hidden name="cart" value={myJSON}></textarea>
```